# Model field property not displaying the value in View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am creating this MVC site and I am having an issue where the model value is not getting displayed when it gets to the View. While debugging, I see the property having value set in the model, and voidMethod, as well as the controller. However when it gets to the View, the value shows as null for headline.

Model

```
Public class tbl
{
    public string headline { get; set; }

}
```

VoidMethod that sets the property value:

```
Public class voidmethods
{
    Public tbl getHeadline()
    {
        tbl t =new tbl();
        t.headline="hello";
        return tbl;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
Public ActionResult Inedx()
{
    voidmethods voidmethods = new voidmethods();
    voidmethods.getHeadline();
    return view();

}
```

View

```
<h>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.headline)</h>
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. Please refer to this article to see the various ways you can pass your variables from `Controller` to `View`: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the model `voidmethods.getHeadline()` to the view 
and in view you need to use these model to print `headline`

Model

```
    public class tbl
    {
        public string headline { get; set; }
    }

    public class voidmethods
    {
        public tbl getHeadline()
        {
            tbl t =new tbl();
            t.headline="hello";
            return t;
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        voidmethods voidmethods = new voidmethods();
        var model= voidmethods.getHeadline();
        return View(model);
    }
```

As `voidmethods.getHeadline()` return the instance of `tbl` you need to use same `tbl` on view
View

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.tbl
<body>
    <h>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.headline)</h>
</body>
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HAdlNo)

Answer (score 1):

The controller should be sending the view model back to the view like this

```
public ActionResult Inedx()
{
    tbl tbl= new tbl();
    tbl.getHeadline();
    return view(tbl);

}
```

Also remember to reference the model in the view

```
@model //your model namespace here
```

Set the attribute in your tbl class, so the tbl class becomes

```
public class tbl
{
    public string headline { get; set; }
    public string getHeadline()
    {
        headline="hello";
        return headline;
    }
}
```

Another option is to set it in the controller

```
public ActionResult Inedx()
{
    tbl tbl= new tbl();
    tbl.headline = "Hello";
    return view(tbl);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still returns null.

Comment: You are not setting the property of the tbl class well. your model is actually tbl. see my edits

Comment: It still returns null

Comment: I see the values being set as I `Step Into` the debugging. but once the `getheadline` method executes, the values get set to null

Comment: Are you using what I answered? Because it works for me, I also edited my answer